# Using code(extension development) can we change popup settings for particular website in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i have a chrome extension that open a window using window.open, which is in a test.js file other than background.js
i am not able to use
    chrome.windows.create();
method directly in test.js since it fires error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined"
so i use
    window.open('mysite.com');
chrome browser does not allow to open popup. its says popups are blocked. user have to allow the the popup for that site.
Is there any way by code through i can allow popup for a particular site?
or 
Any way i can use chrome.windows.create(); in any js file other than background.js ?

Comment: If `test.js` is a *Content Script*, you can send a message to your background page to open the popup for you.

Comment: @sunilrxg: Did you try my answer below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically allow popups (afaik), but you can use (indirectly) **[`chrome.windows.create()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create)**.

Since **[`chrome.windows`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html)** is only available in the background-page, you need to utilize **[Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple)**, in order to communicate between the content-script and the background-page:

**In *content-script*:**

```
/* Instead of `window.open(someURL);` */
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: openWindow,
    url: someURL
});
```

**In *background-page*:**

```
/* Listen for and respond to messages from content-scripts */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
    if ((msg.action === 'openWindow') && (msg.url !== undefined)) {
        chrome.windows.create({ url: msg.url });
    }
});
```

<sub>(Of course, you can specify other parameters as well, besides the URL.)</sub>